# Word for: older than legacy

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, computing

In computer programming "legacy" usually means some older version of something, that is still there for compatibility reasons.

Is there any other technical word to describe something even older and still there for compatibility?

Comment: I think "legacy" pretty much covers it. Unless... I mean, how old are we talkin'? Is your software compatible with the Antikythera Mechanism or Jaquet-Droz automata?

Comment: Hi. I need to present both alternatives, this is why I can't just use legacy for both, it would confuse people

Comment: Hmm... Well, strictly speaking, I don't know if there's a proper English term. But the Jargon File has some [options](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/D/dusty-deck.html).

Comment: As you say, *legacy* means an *older* version that is still there for compatibility reasons.  But then you say you have some older code that is there for compatibility reasons but you can't call it *legacy* because it's too old?!?  Wouldn't that just be "older legacy code?"  And really if I were to define *legacy code* I'd say it was code that was inherited from an earlier version of the software.  It may not necessarily be there for compatibility reasons; it could be there because it works and it costs too much to rewrite.

Comment: Sometimes **obsolete** code runs on newer systems, not through any particular planning, but simply because it's vanilla enough not to break anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

obsolete

> Obsolete refers to outdated computer hardware, software, technology, services or practices that are no longer used, even if they are in working condition. A technology often becomes obsolete when replaced by a newer or better technology.
>   ([techopedia](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/2115/obsolete))

Comment: But *obsolete* means it's no longer used, whereas OP is looking for a word to describe code that is still there for compatibility reasons.